# Pandas Series Add/Subtraction not Working on Python Slicing

Tags: python, pandas

I have been struggling to wrap my head around this issue. So, I can't seem to understand this behavior:

```
import pandas as pd

close = [12,15,18,15,15,17,16,21,20,24,23,28]
high = [25,19,43,15,20,50,22,61,12,30,35,40]
_close = pd.Series(data=close)
_high = pd.Series(data=high)

print(_close-_high)

d_close = _close[1:].copy()
d_high = _high[:-1].copy()
print(d_close-d_high)
```

Running this gives this output:
[link to output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HPPn.png)

I have spent hours fixing this without any success :(
Googling, I came across chained assignment in pandas. I couldn't understand much and was helping somebody help me fix this.

Really grateful for your kind help.

Thank you.

Comment: Fix what? what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You will see the problem if you `print(_close[1:])` and `print(_high[:-1])`. The indices on which they are indexed remain the same as your original series even if you have sliced them and taken a copy.

`_close` has indices from 1 to 11 whereas `_high` has indices from 0 to 10. When you subtract, those values at the same indices/rows are subtracted. Since there is no value at some indices, a NaN value is generated.

All you need to do is call the `reset_index()` function as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

close = [12,15,18,15,15,17,16,21,20,24,23,28]
high = [25,19,43,15,20,50,22,61,12,30,35,40]
_close = pd.Series(data=close)
_high = pd.Series(data=high)

print(_close-_high)

d_close = _close[1:].copy().reset_index();
d_high = _high[:-1].copy().reset_index()
print(d_close-d_high)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro! You saved me a lot of time by answering this.